# Using a custom font with CSS

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I am attempting to get a custom font.

When I try, the font doesn't work and it uses custom Times new Roman.

This is my code in the style sheet:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "ARBONNIE";
    src: url(Custom/ARBONNIE.ttf);
}
font {
    font-family: "ARBONNIE";
}
```

But, when I view the website, the custom font is not shown.
It's the correct directory and everything.  Please help :(

Answer (score 5):

Your use of `@font-face` is not compatible with all browsers. A useful tool for generating cross-browser `@font-face` code is here: [Font Squirrel `@font-face` Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator). That generator will give you all of the files you need as well as a complete example that you can use to test in various browsers.

Ultimately on your page, your CSS will look something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BitstreamVeraSerifBold';
    src: url('verasebd-webfont.eot');
    src: url('verasebd-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('verasebd-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('verasebd-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('verasebd-webfont.svg#BitstreamVeraSerifBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

.custom-font {
    font-family: 'BitstreamVeraSerifBold';
}
```

Note that I'm using the font `BitstreamVeraSerifBold` here, with the font files in the same directory as the CSS file.

And in your HTML:

```
<span class="custom-font">Your text here</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using it for the entire website?

where you put "font { }" is where you should assign the font whether it is a div,a,p,span,body,etc.

So try `body { font-family: "ARBONNIE"; }` hope it helps.

Comment: I wan't to assign it just to Font

Comment: the font tag is a depreciated element. assign the font to your body tag similar to what I did above and it should work. if you need more assistance I will need your url to the site

Comment: I don't want it for the whole freaking website!  I just want it for one thing.

Comment: if you don't want it for the whole website it has to be assigned to a specific class/id/element. Also, don't forget to include different file formats for different browsers if you need cross-browser support

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential issues:

@font-face is only supported in certain browsers and with certain font types

IE9 supports @font-face for .eot fonts
IE8 and earlier do not support @font-face
Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari support @font-face for *.ttf and *.otf fonts

Are you testing this in IE?  The *.ttf won't work.

Second possible issue - try doing this without the word "font" as a selector.  Either use a unique selector or assign it to the body or p selectors

edit - saw you want this for one area.  Pick a new selector, use the font style like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "ARBONNIE";
  src: url("Custom/ARBONNIE.ttf");}

ArbFont {font:16pt "Arbonnie";}
```

Then change your html to use the new selector such as this:

```
<div id="ArbFont">This is in Arbonnie</div>
```