# HTML / javascript - change font family

Tags: javascript, html, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a custom font with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253910/using-a-custom-font-with-css)

Is there a way to change my font family to something I have downloaded rather than something in the default?

I have downloaded some fonts on www.dafont.com and I want to use it on my HTML/Javascript application.

Any help and advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the fonts to "Web fonts" use the below URL in order to convert it
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

after converting it, you will find a package contains Font/CSS include it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense in using a font you've downloaded in a web application as it will not be available for your users. Instead, you could you [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts), which allows you to include a variety of fonts in your site.

example:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kavoon' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

css:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Kavoon', cursive;
}
```